# Проблемы со cлайдером Bootstrap в Joomla

Tags: joomla, bootstrap

Как правильно добавить слайдер Bootstrap в шаблон Joomla?
В `index.php` есть блок, который отвечает за вывод модуля в данной позиции.
Загружаю модуль через админ-панель, первое изображение отображается, но не меняются слайды даже вручную.

Код:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('as-position-5')): ?>
<div id="slider-row">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="as-position-5" style="themeHtml5" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>


Если этот блок полностью заменить на 
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!— Carousel items —>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img src="/www/jupgrade/templates/as002059free/images/gallery/london.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/www/jupgrade/templates/as002059free/images/gallery/rio.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/www/jupgrade/templates/as002059free/images/gallery/moscow.jpg"></div>
</div>
<!— Carousel nav —>
<a class="carousel-control left» href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Выходит то же самое.